# Add Attribute to p Tag of Post Content

Tags: html, editor, the-content, post-content, wp-kses

I would like the default `<p>` elements that are added to the (TinyMCE) editor when users post content, to have a `dir` attribute as well.

**Reasoning**:
When the editor is displayed to users, it is wrapped in an html element with a dir attribute (determined by locale). Thus, the text direction to the user (while he is writing the content) reflects his locale.

However, the `p` elements that are part of the user's content (which I will be storing in the database) do not have the `dir` attribute attached.

I would like to attach it so that when the content is later retrieved from the database, it is shown the same way that it looked to the user/author when he wrote it.

How can I add the `dir` attribute to the `p` tags by default?

**Another Approach**: I have directionality buttons as part of my editor, if I can select these buttons by default, this will take care of the problem as well.

Thank you.

Comment: The `<p>` tags are added by `wpautop()` during output. It would probably make more sense to save meta data that specifies the author's original direction. Then prior to outputting the content, check the meta value and add a class to the entire wrapping element for the content.

Comment: That sounds like it might work. I'm not too keen on how to insert and retrieve post metadata (I'm just tweaking a q&a plugin) but I guess that's for another question if necessary. Thanks.

Comment: @theyuv It's very, _very_ easy - you can just use the built-in "Custom Fields" metabox to allow the user to add/edit/delete custom fields, and then pull them in with `get_post_meta( $post_id, 'name_of_field', true )`

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Yup, I'm working on it now. Just difficult in the sense that I have to find where my plugin writes the posts to the DB and stuff (I'm a novice at php and WP). But I think I should be able to do this. And yes, the WP functions make it easy. Thanks.